# How to recursively pass up all data from form?

Tags: reactjs

I've got a form, it looks like this:

```
export default class BookingForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: props.data};
    }

    render() {
        const {booking, vehicleSelect, vehicleData, customer, drivers, fees, occasions} = this.props;

        return (
                <form className="grid-form">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <label>Is this a new or returning customer?</label>
                            <RadioMenu name="repeat_customer">
                                <RadioButton value="NEW">New Customer</RadioButton>
                                <RadioButton value="EXIST">Returning Customer</RadioButton>
                            </RadioMenu>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="row new-customer-row">
                        <div className="col-1-2">
                            <label htmlFor="customer.first_name">First Name</label>
                            <Input id="customer.first_name" name="customer.first_name" type="text"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-1-2">
                            <label htmlFor="customer.last_name">Last Name</label>
                            <Input id="customer.last_name" name="customer.last_name" type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    // .. more inputs ..
```

Where `<RadioMenu>` renders a list of `<RadioButton>`s which in turn contain an `<Input>`.

`<Input>` just looks like this:

```
export default function Input(attrs) {
    return <input {...attrs}/>;
}
```

I made it a React component hoping I can do something useful with it.

Basically, I want all the form data to be stuffed into `this.data.INPUT_NAME` as soon as the input is changed. If the input name contains a `.` then I want to put it into a sub-object. For example, `customer.last_name` will be stored in `this.state.data.customer.last_name`. I also want to to use `this.state.data` to set the initial value for all the `Input` elements without having to explicitly add a `value` attribute to each of them; it should just know what value to pull out of the data object by using the input's name.

I don't know how to approach this. My first thought is that instead of returning the `<form>` I should put it into a variable, and then pre-process it, adding `onChange` and `value` attributes to anything of type `Input`, but even I try that, I don't think it would work on my `RadioMenu` because `RadioMenu` is not of type `Input` and I don't think I could recurse down into its children.

I could try using this [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) feature but the warnings are scaring me away.

I haven't looked into Flux/Reflux/Redux/xyz yet, but I don't think I really want to incorporate another framework this early in the game; I want to understand how to approach this properly before tucking it away.

So, how can I get all my form data into `this.state.data`?

---

The radio widgets look like this. I'm open to changing them if necessary. This is my first custom input widget.

```
// RadioMenu.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {cloneWithProps} from '../helpers/react-helpers';
import Input from './Input';

export default class RadioMenu extends Input {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: props.value};
    }

    onChange = ev => {
        this.setState({value: ev.target.value});
        if(this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange(ev);
        }
    };

    render() {
        let {children, name, onChange, ...attrs} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="radio-horizontal radio-menu" {...attrs}>
                {cloneWithProps(children, btn => ({
                    name,
                    checked: btn.props.value == this.state.value,
                    onChange: this.onChange
                }))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// RadioButton.jsx
export default function RadioButton({children, ...attrs}) {
    return (
        <label className="checkable">
            <input type="radio" {...attrs}/>
            <span>{children}</span>
        </label>
    );
}
```

I was trying to use inheritance has so I could pluck out all the `Input`s, regardless if they're custom or not, but I can't seem to get this to work in React. `mycomp.type instanceof Input` doesn't return true for sub-classes. I know React suggests composition over inheritance, but I don't know how to make that work.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is the reason we have libraries/patterns like Redux/Flux, but that doesn't mean it's not possible to solve without React, just a little bit harder.

In this specific case, you have a few options.

### Child-Parent Events

If you change your `<RadioButton />` component to accept an `onChange` handler, then you can listen for changes to the button and put them straight into your state.

```
function RadioButton(props) {
  return (
    // pass the onChange prop down
    <input type="radio" onChange={props.onChange} />
  );
}
```

Then update your `<BookingForm />` component to make use of this new handler prop.

```
const setRadioState = e => this.setState({ radio: e.target.value });
// ...
<RadioMenu name="repeat_customer">
  <RadioButton value="NEW" onChange={setRadioState}>New Customer</RadioButton>
  <RadioButton value="EXIST" onChange={setRadioState}>Returning Customer</RadioButton>
</RadioMenu>
```

### Accessing the Form

You can listen to the form for the `submit` event then iterate through the form's elements to build up an object you can put in your state.

```
render() {
  // ...
  <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
  // ...
},
onSubmit(e) {
  const form = e.target;
  const elements = form.elements;
  // remove numeric keys
  const keys = Object.keys(elements).filter(k => /[^\d]/.test(k);
  const data = {};
  keys.forEach(k => data[k] = elements[k].value);
  this.setState(data);
}
```

If you aren't listening to the `submit` event and want to submit with say, a button press, then you'll need to use [`refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) to get a instance of the form.

I'm more or less just making this approach up off the top of my head, so be wary of edge cases.

Comment: The point of what I'm asking is that I don't want to add explicit `onChange` handlers to every single input. I want it to be automated based on name. I might have to do some special handling for my custom widgets, but I'll only have to do it once per input type. Secondly, I don't want to do this onSubmit. By collecting it into the form's state immediately I can do all my show/hide logic based on that.

Comment: If you want to get data from a child component into a parent component, passing down function props is the only way. You can use the LinkedState mixin, but the [official advice](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) is not to, and use explicit handlers instead.

Comment: If I have to pass down function props, isn't there a way to pre-process the form and add all the function props in an automated way?

Comment: Nvm. That LinkedStateMixin looks more or less like what I wanted. I might take the source and tweak it to meet my needs. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's called LinkedStateMixin. It handles `onChange` handler and calls `setState(value)`. You can shortcut the passing down by passing a spread if you want: `<Child {...this.props} />`.

Comment: Forms are a bit of a pain point for React, but that's primarily because of the nature of component local state. When you move your application state out to a centralized store, you get abstractions like [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/5.2.3/#/getting-started?_k=oqsr8e).

Answer (score 0):

[ReactLink](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) will do what you want, but it's on its way out the door. Fortunately, it's easy to recreate this functionality in just a few lines of code.

Instead of using `<input>`, you can use this component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class LinkedStateInput extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {value, ...attrs} = this.props;
        return <input {...attrs} value={value.value} onChange={ev => value.requestChange(ev.target.value)} />;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
<LinkedStateInput value={this.linkState('passenger_count')} type="text"/>
```

Now just add a method to your `BookingForm` to handle the state updates:

```
linkState(name) {
    return {
        value: _.get(this.state.data, name, ''),
        requestChange: value => {
            let data = _.clone(this.state.data);
            _.set(data, name, value);
            this.setState({data})
        }
    }
}
```

I've used lodash here to handle deep sets/gets.

`RadioMenu` becomes even simpler because now it doesn't even have to remember its own state:

```
export default function RadioMenu({children, name, valueLink}) {
    return (
        <div className="radio-horizontal radio-menu">
            {
                valueLink
                ? cloneWithProps(children, btn => ({
                    name,
                    checked: btn.props.value === valueLink.value,
                    onChange: ev => valueLink.requestChange(ev.target.value)
                }))
                : cloneWithProps(children, {name})
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```